# sqlite query in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have this query

```
public Cursor control(String a){
    return mDb.query(ProductsMetaData.C_TABLE, null,ProductsMetaData.A+ "=?" , new String[] {String.valueOf(a)},  null, null, null, null);
}
```

and it works.
Now I need  to implement the "AND" because I want only rows where `ProductsMetaData.A = a` and `ProductsMetaData.B = b` but what I'm doing doesn't work.

```
public Cursor control(String a, String b){
    return mDb.query(ProductsMetaData.C_TABLE, null,ProductsMetaData.A+ "=?" + ProductsMetaData.B + "=?" , new String[] {String.valueOf(a), String.valueOf(b)},  null, null, null, null);
}
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add the `AND` keyword:

```
ProductsMetaData.A + "=? AND " + ProductsMetaData.B + "=?"
```

Also your parameters `a` and `b` are already Strings, so you can simply use:

```
new String[] {a, b}
```

---

> Can I ask you how can I implement update and delete too?

Delete is easy enough:

```
public int delete(String a, String b) {
    return mDb.delete(ProductsMetaData.C_TABLE, ProductsMetaData.A + "=? AND " + ProductsMetaData.B + "=?", new String[] {a, b});
}
```

Updates require a ContentValues object:

```
public int update(String newA, String newB, String oldA, String oldB) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ProductsMetaData.A, newA);
    values.put(ProductsMetaData.B, newB);
    return mDb.update(ProductsMetaData.C_TABLE, values, ProductsMetaData.A + "=? AND " + ProductsMetaData.B + "=?", new String[] {oldA, oldB});
}
```

One final note, if you find yourself using `ProductsMetaData.A + "=? AND " + ProductsMetaData.B + "=?"` numerous times, you can save it in a `static final` variable just like `C_TABLE`, `A`, and `B`:

```
private static final String WHERE_A_B = ProductsMetaData.A + "=? AND " + ProductsMetaData.B + "=?";
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right! Can I ask you how can I implement update and delete too?